# How to avoid boxing bytes in array in custom datasource?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a custom Spark datasource and want the schema to include a row of primitive byte array type.

My problem is that the bytes in the resulting byte array get boxed: the output then has type `WrappedArray$ofRef`. This means that each byte is represented as a java.lang.Object. Although I can work around this, I'm concerned about the computational and memory overheads, which are of critical importance for my application. I really just want primitive arrays!

Below is a minimal example which demonstrates this behaviour.

```
class DefaultSource extends SchemaRelationProvider with DataSourceRegister {

    override def shortName(): String = "..."

    override def createRelation(
                                    sqlContext: SQLContext,
                                    parameters: Map[String, String],
                                    schema: StructType = new StructType()
                               ): BaseRelation = {
        new DefaultRelation(sqlContext)
    }
}

class DefaultRelation(val sqlContext: SQLContext) extends BaseRelation with PrunedFilteredScan {

    override def schema = {
        StructType(
            Array(
                StructField("key", ArrayType(ByteType))
            )
        )
    }

    override def buildScan(
                              requiredColumnNames: Array[String],
                              filterArr: Array[Filter]
                          ): RDD[Row] = {
        testRDD
    }

    def testRDD = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(
        List(
            Row(
                Array[Byte](1)
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Using this sample datasource as follows:

```
def schema = StructType(Array(StructField("key", ArrayType(ByteType))))
val rows = sqlContext
        .read
        .schema(schema)
        .format("testdatasource")
        .load
        .collect()
println(rows(0)(0).getClass)
```

Then generates the following output:

```
class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef
```

Inspecting the result type further in the debugger confirms that the bytes in the WrappedArray are indeed boxed - and for some reason their type is erased all the way up to `java.lang.Object` (rather than to `java.lang.Byte`).

Note that using an RDD directly, without going through the datasource APIs, leads to the expected result of primitive byte arrays.

Any suggestions as to how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so for primitive byte arrays I should have used `BinaryType` instead of `Array(Byte)` as the column type. This fixes the problem.

Out of curiosity, if we change `ArrayType(ByteType)` to e.g. `ArrayType(LongType)` in the examples above, we actually get a runtime exception indicating that boxed longs are expected. So, it seems that primitives in Spark SQL arrays are always boxed.